# Errors found, tag div or p, Valid XHTML

Tags: html, forms, validation, xhtml-transitional

I am trying to validate my document as XHTML 1.0 Transitional (W3C).
I have the following error:
document type does not allow element "div" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag
which corresponds to this code:

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

also error: document type does not allow element "p" here; missing one of "object", "applet", "map", "iframe", "button", "ins", "del" start-tag

```
<p><span class="form-span">Do <input type="checkbox" name="own" value="yes" /> rent <input type="checkbox" name="rent" value="yes" /> other <input type="checkbox" name="rentother" value="Other" /></span></p>
```

code fragment:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional
...
<body>
<form id="form1" ...>
...
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<p><span class="form-span">Do <input type="checkbox" name="own" value="yes" /> rent <input type="checkbox" name="rent" value="yes" /> other <input type="checkbox" name="rentother" value="Other" /></span></p>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>

<span style="width:100%;">
...
<input id="i1oc_yes" type="radio" name="i1oc" value="yes" />
<input id="i1oc_no" type="radio" name="i1oc" value="no" />
...
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
...
</span>
```

Please let me know what is the problem.
Thanks!

Comment: The problem should be fairly clear. "document type does not allow element "p" here". You haven't shown us where the `<p>` is though, so it isn't clear what about "here" is wrong. The last code sample you provide doesn't have that error (at least if you add in a `<body>`).

Comment: Could You, please, provide us a link, so that we could review what is happening there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Your problem consists of the following as stated by validator

> One possible cause for this message is that you have attempted to put
>   a block-level element (such as `<p>` or `<table>`) inside an inline
>   element (such as `<a>`, `<span>`, or `<font>`).

So, in Your code, I see, that `<div>` element is inside the `<span>` element which is not a valid XHTML.

Reference:

[Block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

[Inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente)

and as stated on [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente):

> Generally, inline elements may contain only data and other inline
>   elements.